# Set the Value of a dropdown in Sharepoint based on text Field

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list, the users are filling in the form and there is a hidden column that includes the Status. It should be "approved" by default if the text in field "Number of day" is 2 or less, otherwise the dropdown field should be on status "pending".

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Test code for your reference:

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#Status").closest("tr").hide();
  $("[title='Number of day']").keyup(function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
    if($(this).val()<=2){
      $("[title='Status']").val("pending")
    }else{
      $("[title='Status']").val("approved")
    }
  })
})

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however I am note sure where to add this to reflect?

Comment: Add a script editor web part and insert this code into the web part. Pay attention to modify the code to adapt to your environment.